# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/mq/SpyObjectMessage when upgrading JBoss 4.0.5 to 4.2.2

Tags: java, jboss, jms

But the class found in jboss-4.2.2.GA/client/jbossall-client.jar. Still the application is throwing exception.

Should we move the file to server/default/lib

Comment: Where is the jar right now? If your application using this jar, then It should be in your application lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by using ObjectMessage by replacing SpyObjectMessage. SpyObjectMessage seems like JBoss mq implementation (JBoss 4.0.5)

Answer (score 0):

First lets clarify whether the dependency of this class is in your webapp or from jboss itself. If it is in your webapp, better copy this jar (provided you already confirmed that this jar contains the complained class) to webapp corresponding `WEB-INF/lib` folder. In case if is from jboss startup itself, better copy the jar to `server/default/lib folder` (assuming you are using default profile of jboss server)